# Hapi CORS while using Nginx as load balancer

Tags: nginx, cors, load-balancing, hapi.js

I have an Nginx with wide open core as seen on [enable-cors.org](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html). Which I am able to see the following on a `GET` request

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
```

However when I try from chrome with `POST` values I am getting an error like this;

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://0.0.0.0/user' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I am trying to get the header **Authorization** from the response of my `POST` request

Comment: how is your cors config on your request setup?

Comment: Request is just an `axios` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it.

1. Enable CORS in Hapi server block

   ```
   const server = Hapi.Server({
     debug: { request: ["error"] },
     port: process.env.APP_PORT,
     host: process.env.APP_SERVER,
     routes: {
       cors: true
     }
   });
   ```
2. Create a reverse proxy in `Nginx`

   ```
   proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $remote_user;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   ```
3. Watch headers
   You will see an error saying **multiple value for header Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**
4. Suppress the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from Hapi by hiding it with `nginx` config

   ```
   proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
   ```

### EDIT

Managed to get it working without `nginx` with following values in Hapi server block

```
cors: {
  origin: "ignore",
  additionalHeaders: ["Authorization"],
  additionalExposedHeaders: ["Authorization"]
},
```